# MongoDB giving Error While importing JSON, not all the documents get imported

Tags: json, mongodb, mongoimport, studio3t

```
Import JSON done
Target: cloud
Total time: 00:17

Transferring documents...
[JSON] : Message: {"Errors":["Request rate is large"]}
Elapsed time: 00:17
```

some of the documents get imported only.

Comment: Is this a real MongoDb instance or CosmosDb with a MongoDb API interface?

Comment: CosmosDB with MongoDB API interface